# noun for "something to use/give if no other match"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If you cannot find what you looking for use/give ***this*** instead.
What do you call ***this***?

1. if someone wants a "pen" give them a "book"
2. if someone wants a "shoe" give them a "sock"
3. if someone wants a "chair" give them a "table"
4. otherwise give them a "paper"

> "paper" is the _____

Comment: Paper is the fallback or the alternative or the last resort.

Comment: Are you using 'this' and 'xxx' as the same thing? Is it a default value?

Comment: In 1-3, you seem to be trying to give people something other than what they asked for. What's the rule you're using?

Comment: @Lawrence rule 1-3 is arbitrary. Basically if no rule are matched, it will yield the ____

Answer (score 1):

### **[Default](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/default)**

> A preselected option adopted by a computer program or other mechanism when no alternative is specified by the user or programmer.

It's often used in programming, but the same applies outside of IT.

> Paper is the default option.

**edit**

> Paper is the default.

You can use it as a noun too.

Comment: "default" implies that the "user" have **not** specify. this one should imply that it will be used if **specified** option is not available

Comment: @dna01 "Default" can be used in both the case of an _unspecified_ option, or an option that is _explicitly requested but unavailable_. "We will default to serving vanilla ice cream if you order a flavor that we do not have".